# How to increase cordApp heap size in intelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, corda

My cordApp is using a 3rd party service that require more heap space but i am unable to increase the heap size limit while running it from IntelliJ IDEA. I have seen following docs:

> https://docs.corda.net/running-a-node.html

but i want more heap space while i run my app on mock network from intellij IDE. I have tried following solutions:

1. Setting VM Option -Xmx1048m in run configrations
2. Editing idea.vmoptions
3. (Mac) Changing Preferences > Build,Execution,Deployment > Compiler [params]
4. (Mac) Changing Preferences > Build,Execution,Deployment > Compiler > Kotlin Compiler [params]

Every time i run

> Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()

i get heapsize of around 209715200 bytes (209 MBs)

**Edit:**

idea.vmoptions file

> -Xms1g
>   -Xmx4g
>   -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
>   -XX:+UseCompressedOops
>   -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
>   -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
>   -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
>   -ea
>   -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
>   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
>   -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
>   -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
>   -Xverify:none
>   
>   -XX:ErrorFile=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_idea_%p.log
>   -XX:HeapDumpPath=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_idea.hprof
>   -Xbootclasspath/a:../lib/boot.jar

Comment: Can you post the contents of the idea.vmoptions file please?
Sounds like this isn't a Corda specific problem

Comment: I am using corda V2 and i think i cannot change individual node heapsize as v2 corda.jar is compiled with VM-Args: Xmx200m. I cloned a fresh copy of V3 github.com/corda/cordapp-example planning to try http://docs.corda.r3.com/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.testing.driver/-node-parameters/set-maximum-heap-size.html

Comment: @OmerShafiq Why do we need heap during compiling the code ?

Comment: @Shinchan i added a third party dependency to my build.gradle and my cordApp compiles and starts absolutely fine but when i start a corda flow, In my example 'Create an IOU' it throws exception of going out of memory (heap space). *NOTE I am not using any functionality of the newly included dependency.

Comment: With V2 cordapp-example everything works fine after updating build.gradle with new dependency but when i try to access functions of the newly included dependency i get following:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: System memory 209715200 must be at least 471859200. Please increase heap size

Comment: With V3 cordapp-example i have tried updating NodeParameter setMaximumHeapSize = 1g but it also doesn't help. As in v3 after updating build.gradle and building successfully i cannot even 'Create IOUs' as Flows go out of memory while executing.

Comment: idea.vmoptions file is for IDEAs memory not anything you run within it. How exactly are you running the mock node? Can you paste your run configuration?

Answer (score 2):

I used Corda V3 and updated NodeDriver.kt and it worked for me

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
// No permissions required as we are not invoking flows.
val nodeParams = NodeParameters(maximumHeapSize = "800m")
val user = User("user1", "test", permissions = setOf("ALL"))
driver(DriverParameters(isDebug = true, waitForAllNodesToFinish = true)) {
    val (partyA, partyB, partyC) = listOf(
            startNode(nodeParams, providedName = CordaX500Name("PartyA", "London", "GB"), rpcUsers = listOf(user), maximumHeapSize = "800m"),
            startNode(nodeParams, providedName = CordaX500Name("PartyB", "New York", "US"), rpcUsers = listOf(user), maximumHeapSize = "800m"),
            startNode(nodeParams, providedName = CordaX500Name("PartyC", "Paris", "FR"), rpcUsers = listOf(user), maximumHeapSize = "800m")).map { it.getOrThrow() }
    startWebserver(partyA,"800m")
    startWebserver(partyB,"800m")
    startWebserver(partyC,"800m")
}}
```